# How to drag a borderless FMX form on the screen through another object?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I am trying to make a form draggable on the screen, i.e. that I could grab it and move it around the screen. Its transparent and has no borders, however an image serves to be the background for other controls. I want to use the image's events to control dragging of the form. How can I do that?

I have found the DragEnter, DragLeave, DragStart methods which have this TDragObject argument, I don't know about.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Which is the unit where Perform is contained as its not in WinAPI.Windows, WinAPI.Messages nor in Windows.

Comment: Perform is a method of TControl. Similar to SendMessage but it directly delivers the message to WindowProc.

Comment: Ok, but I can't seem to find a unit in FMX for it... I have these in uses; WinAPI.Windows, WinAPI.Messages, Windows, System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.Rtti, System.Classes, System.UITypes, System.Variants, System.Math, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Objects, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Edit, FMX.Effects, FMX.TreeView, FMX.Grid, FMX.TabControl, FMX.Memo, Data.Bind.EngExt, Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt, Data.Bind.Components, FMX.Ani;

Comment: That's my wrong, I didn't notice the firemonkey tag. The linked question is for windows. For windows, you can use SendMessage in winapi.windows, for others, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to do it manually.

Here's some delphi/windows code from a form with a transparent Image (TransImage) on it, no borders etc
The events are in the form for the Image so Top & Left refer to TMainScanForm.Top/Left.

This will drag your form around using the image events to detect the clicks and moves

```
...

// Mouse Drag Control
MouseDown: Boolean;
TopLeft,
MouseStart: TPoint;

...

procedure TMainScanForm.TransImageMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  MouseDown := (Button = mbLeft);
  if MouseDown then
  begin
    MouseStart.X := X;
    MouseStart.Y := Y;
    TopLeft := ClientToScreen(MouseStart);
    TopLeft.X := TopLeft.X - X;
    TopLeft.Y := TopLeft.Y - Y;
    end;
end;

procedure TMainScanForm.TransImageMouseMove( Sender: TObject;
                                  Shift: TShiftState;
                                  X, Y: Integer);
var
  NewPoint: TPoint;
begin
  if MouseDown  then
  begin
    NewPoint.X := X;
    NewPoint.Y := Y;
    NewPoint := ClientToScreen(NewPoint);    // On Screen
    NewPoint.Y := NewPoint.Y - MouseStart.Y; // New Onscreen
    NewPoint.X := NewPoint.X - MouseStart.X;
    Top := NewPoint.Y;
    Left := NewPoint.X;
    Refresh;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainScanForm.TransImageMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  MouseDown := False;
end;
```

Comment: Very clever, I'll try it out in a few days.

Comment: Why there's a `Refresh` call after you change the form's position ? Is that some speciality of FMX forms they need to be forced to repaint when their position is changed ?

Comment: This code is written for VCL. It isn't a good solution for Firemonkey. It fails on fast mouse movements and fails if the mouse cursor is near the form edges. Mouse events (Down/Move/Up) in Firemonkey are almost different form VCL.

Comment: @mh I did state it was windows - It's just to give an example of how it could be done. If it needs adaptation for FM then, err, it does. Works fine for windows no matter where you click.

As for the Refresh TLama there are a lot of other controls on this window/image and the "apparent window" is not rectangular. I originally wrote it about 5 years ago, I just copied and pasted as an example, I must have put it there for a reason!