# How do I drag the form from other objects in a FMX application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I would like to drag a form from other objects the same way it worked in VCL applications when using the `SendMessage` function. I know there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197111/how-to-drag-a-borderless-fmx-form-on-the-screen-through-another-object) post which asked the same thing, but the only answer that was given was for VCL applications by mistake.

In VCL applications I would normally use:

```
ReleaseCapture;
SendMessage(Form1.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
```

But since that no longer works I cannot use it.

So how can I move a form from other objects?

Comment: On Windows, a `TForm` is still a Win32 window (but none of its child controls are), so I would think that solution would still work.  The difference being that in FMX, `TForm.Handle` is not a Win32 `HWND`, but you can get the `HWND` using [`FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND).

Comment: On a side note, the customary way to initiate a drag of a window is to use `WM_SYSCOMAND|SC_DRAGMOVE` (where `SC_DRAGMOVE` is `$F012`) instead of `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN|HTCAPTION`.

Comment: `SendMessage` gets a Undeclared Identifier error. Would `TMessageManager.SendMessage` be able to replace its functonality? And if yes, how do I structure the parameters since `TMessageManager.SendMessage` only accepts 2 parameters. Also `WM_SYSCOMAND` and `HTCAPTION` don't get recognized either.

Comment: No, you cannot use `TMessageManager` for this, that is just for internal messaging within the app. This needs to use the Win32 `SendMessage()` for sending messages to a Win32 window. That `SendMessage()` (and `WM_SYSCOMAND` and `HTCAPTION`) are declared in the `Windows` unit, do you have that in your `uses`? Or, just import `SendMessage()` manually from `user32.dll` using an `external` declaration (and define the `WM_SYSCOMAND` and `HTCAPTION` constants in your code, they are `$0112` and `2`, respectively).